# Allowing some enabled and disabled option on collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to populate a dropdown box on a view that has all the states. This works just fine:

```
<%= f.collection_select :state_id, @states, :id, :name %>
```

Now, I need to make the following: Some states are going to be disabled for choosing, but they still have to appear on the dropbown list.

How can I achieve this? (I can populate an additional list for these states).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) internally relies on [`options_from_collection_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) helper.

Rather than using the `collection_select` directly, you can use `select` and pass the result of a `options_from_collection_for_select` call. The reason you may want to call `options_from_collection_for_select` directly, is because this method also accepts an optional `selected` parameter that could be used to pass a value for the `disabled` items.

> `selected` can also be a hash, specifying both `:selected` and/or `:disabled` values as required.

The value of the option can be one of the following

> If selected is specified as a value or array of values, the element(s) returning a match on value_method will be selected option tag(s).
>
> If selected is specified as a Proc, those members of the collection that return true for the anonymous function are the selected values.

Therefore, if you pass `{ disabled: [1, 3, 5] }` the items `1, 3, 5` will be disabled. Of course, the value must match the value of the option. You can also pass a block.

To be honest, this Rails helper looks quite complicated to me. Another option is to still use `select` directly, but create your own helper to generate the string of HTML option items and pass the string directly to the select (which is what `options_from_collection_for_select` is doing, with a not extremely simple API).